# CodeIgniter COUNT with active record?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter.. I want to count the no. of rows having the same order_no.. below is my code.

```
public function get_my_orders() {
        $user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
        $email = $user_data['user_email'];
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('order_details');
            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->group_by('order_no');
            $this->db->order_by('order_no', 'DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
    }
```

Pls help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your select line to look like this:

```
            $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count');
```

Rather than having all fields accessible like they currently are, you will instead only have access to one variable called `count`. To keep all variables accessible and add the count in as well, use this instead:

```
            $this->db->select('*, COUNT(*) as count');
```

Feel free to change the lowercase name for `count`, I'm just using that as an example.

Comment: Unfortunately with the other answer which uses `num_rows`, you still have the database server preparing (if not returning) all results, which can sometimes be slower than asking for the server for the total count.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [$this->db->count_all_results()](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

```
 public function get_my_orders() {
    $user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
    $email = $user_data['user_email'];
        //$this->db->select('*');// no need select as you only want counts
        $this->db->from('order_details');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        //$this->db->group_by('order_no');//no need group_by as you only want counts
        //$this->db->order_by('order_no', 'DESC');//no need order_by as you only want counts            
        return $this->db->count_all_results();;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Codeigniter Manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

```
$query = $this->db->get();
return  $query->num_rows();  //Return total no. of rows here
```

> `$query->num_rows();` will count the total active record return by your query.